# Add SKU column Magento admin sales > order

Tags: php, magento

I've managed to get the fields I want showing up but I can't pull the data in e.g. the SKU data should come from the catalog > manage products.

Magento version in use is 1.5.1.0

[image]
[image]

Basically i need to pull data from 'customer/customer_collection' and 'sales/order_grid_collection' in the same class, is that possible?

Comment: I've got the following code to get the results above:

// SKU
        $this->addColumn('sku', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'index' => 'sku',
        ));

But I know the SKU comes from another block, just don't know how to call the function.

Answer (score 5):

To get all of the Skus in the order, you could use `frame_callback` to look up the Skus for the order in a separate function.

In the `_prepareColumns()` function for your Sku column:

...

```
$this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
                 'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
                 'index' => 'increment_id',
                 'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_skus')
));
```

...

Then add this new function somewhere in your `Grid.php`.

```
public function callback_skus($value, $row, $column, $isExport) {
    $increment_id = $value;
    $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);
    $_items = $_order->getAllItems();
    $skus="";
    foreach ($_items as $item) {
            $skus .= $item->getSku()."<br/>";
    }
    return $skus;
}
```

This will return all of the Skus for the order without a lot of complex joins.

---

**EDIT - 2nd part of the answer**

To enable searching/filtering on the above, you'll need to update the `_prepareCollection()` to the following:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
    ->join(
           'sales/order_item',
           '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
               array(
                     'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'),
               )
    );
    $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Add a new function called `filter_skus()`:

```
public function filter_skus($collection, $column) {
   if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
        "sku like ?"
    , "%$value%");

    return $this;

}
```

and update the `addColumn` for `sku` like this:

...

```
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
                 'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
                 'index' => 'increment_id',
                 'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_skus'),
                 'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filter_skus'),
));
```

...

Notice the new call to `filter_condition_callback` that adds the `where` condition necessary to make the search function.

Comment: Worked like a charm! now I got to do the same for telephone, product name, quantity of purchase and email. Does the concept apply to all of them? what fields do I need to change exactly? 

Thank you so much for taking the time and helping!

Comment: Also is there away the search function can work as well as it doesn't now.

Comment: Yep you can do the same for the rest of them.  To add the other fields you can copy the function in the answer and copy the `addColumn` to add each additional field.  For example, the function `callback_skus` can be duplicated and renamed to `callback_qty` and change `$item->getSku()` to `$item->getQty()`.  Whatever you pass as the `index` is going to get passed to the `frame_callback` as `$value`.  To make the search and filter work you'll need to figure out your `_prepareCollection()` joins.  If you follow the pattern in the 2nd part of the answer (See edits above) then you should be fine.

Comment: See `EDIT` in the answer above for more information about how to make the displayed fields searchable/filterable.  You'll have to do that for any column that you want to add search & filter capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the completed step which were mentioned above in "seanbreeden" post
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15589455/revisions

But for the SKU search functionality I added the one line in this function

```
public function filter_skus($collection, $column) {
   if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->join( array('table_alias'=>'sales_flat_order_item'), 'main_table.entity_id = table_alias.order_id',array('table_alias.sku'));
$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("sku like ?", "%$value%");

    return $this;
}
```

After adding this line search is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1:  Create the Renderer directory under /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order

Step 2:
Create a Block File in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Renderer/Red.php (You can use any name)
<?php


class
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Red extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract

    {
      public function render(Varien_Object $row)

       {

         //$value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());



        $order_id=$row->getData('increment_id');

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementID($order_id);

        $items = $order->getAllItems();

        // print_r($items);exit();

            foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)

                {

                if($item->getSku())

                    {

                    $sku[] = $item->getSku();

                    }

                }

                if(count($sku))

                    {

                    $skutext = implode(',',$sku);

                    }

            $conbinetext=$skutext;

            return $conbinetext;

        }

    }



?>
Step 3: Add the Below Code in
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

$this->addColumn('Shopby',


  array(


  'header'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Sku'),

  'index' => 'shopby',

  'filter'=> false,


  'sortable'=>false,

  'renderer'=> 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Red',// THIS IS WHAT THIS POST IS ALL ABOUT

  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: For not to override magento core functionality, You can create your own module and use the below code in Grid.php

Open app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php

Replace the below function

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            'sales_flat_order_item',
            '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
            array('skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'))
    );
    $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Now put the below code in _prepareColumns() function

```
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
    'index' => 'skus',
    'type' => 'text',
    'width' => '100px',
    'filter'    => false,
));
```

Source: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/12/how-to-add-sku-column-in-sales-order.html